# Was Potiphar, being a captain of an Egyptian guard, likely a eunuch?

Tags: history, sexuality, yosef, egypt

In Genesis, we read the infamous story of Joseph and Potiphar's wife. Potiphar's wife (who is named Zuleikha, at least according Sefer HaYashar) repeatedly makes sexual advances on Joseph, and as we know, Joseph consistently stays true to his morals (not to mention loyalty to Potiphar) and staunchly refuses (even resulting to running away)!

I've always wondered why Zuleikha would make more than one attempt after she is clearly rejected, and why she should would be so "desperate."

But it occurred to me, that possibly Potiphar was a eunuch. In ancient Egypt, court officials were often castrated so that the authoritative powers knew that their "second in commands" were not a threat to their women. Do you think this is a likely scenario for Potiphar? And Zuleikha wasn't being satisfied by her husband physically? (By no means, am I giving her an excuse for her lewd behavior, but it may help me better understand the historical context). Do you think this is a viable possibility?

Comment: The medrash says that potiphars wife snitched on Yosef during the act saying "he did this and this to me" which enrages Potiphar even more. That would be a proof against this. On the other hand, another medrash says that due to Potiphar making advances on Yosef, a Malach came and castrated him, which is why hes called "Potiphera" which is a woman's name

Comment: Gen 37:36 calls him a Seris, which often means eunuch.